# Are there really multiple “conditions” given in the MIT license?

Tags: mit, terminology

It has always bothered me that [the MIT license](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) uses the word “conditions” but only seems to list one condition:

> Permission is hereby granted […] to any person obtaining a copy of this software […] to deal in the Software without restriction […] subject to the following **conditions**:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND […]

(Emphasis mine.) Is the last paragraph considered to be a condition pertaining to the granting of permission? If not, why isn’t the singular “condition” used instead?

Answer (score 2):

> (Emphasis mine.) Is the last paragraph considered to be a condition pertaining to the granting of permission? If not, why isn’t the singular “condition” used instead?

The last paragraph is a warranty disclaimer. Singular vs. plural in `condition` does not matter whether or not you consider this disclaimer as a condition or not.

FWIW a few MIT variants also float around using `condition` rather than `conditions`. And IMHO no sane lawyer or judge would consider the plural vs singular here as having any significance.

Use the MIT and be happy!

Answer (score 1):

There is an additional condition below the warranty clause in the X11 license , so I think that the 
 *SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS"* is also interpreted as a condition.

Note: according wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License there are many MIT licenses, so it also could be a copy past error, on deriving the most famous MIT license (Expact License) from other MIT licenses.